# Where can I find runway usage statistics of USA airports?

Tags: airport, usa, runways, datasets, airport-operations

Ok I’m looking for stats and data of planes arriving at various airports and what runways they use most. I need to know the most used runways for arrivals in airports here in the States. Can anyone point me in a direction where I can easily find this info?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for flight-related data as explained in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Like @CrossRoads said in his answer, there is no data available on which runways are used most. You will need to listen to LiveATC on several days and keep track of the winds to get a rough estimate. For example, from listening to the tower at [KSFO](https://airportnavfinder.com/charts/tpp/KSFO/00375AD.PDF) I gather that they usually land on 1L and 1R and take off on 10L and 10R. However, when the winds are too strong out of the east they use 10L and 10R for landing. [image]

Likewise, if you listen to the tower at KJFK you can tell which runways are in use on any given day. There appears to be more variability there because the winds are much less consistent.

And then there are airports like KOAK and KSJC that have one runway or set of runways that GA aircraft use and one for the big guys.

The airports might keep that kind of information so a call to a few of them might give you some answers, but I am not aware of it being published anywhere.

Comment: SFO rarely lands on 1L/1R (it's an impressive [circling approach](https://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/circle-to-land-1r-sfo-compilation.248854/) used if winds truly demand it, which isn't often at all). [Normal flow](https://www.flysfo.com/about-sfo/sfo-tomorrow/airfield) (used ~83% of the time) has landings on 28L/R and departures on the perpendicular 1L/R (except for aircraft that need full length departures on the 28s). An [alternate plan](https://www.flysfo.com/community/noise-abatement/noise-abatement-procedures) is used at night, winds permitting, for noise abatement.

Comment: @ZachLipton I remember reading about some 1L/1R landings and how difficult they are, but I can’t find them at the moment. I think there were some neighborhood complaints as well since they come in low over residential neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

One can also review the data provided by the airlines at the big airports. For example, [Boston-Logan](http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/about-logan/airport-statistics/) has data by month of the year going back to 1999.

> The statistics included below are compiled by Massport from information provided by the airlines.

You won't find data for the 5,000+ non-towered that is much different than what airnav.com reports.  My home airport's "operations center" where we pay for gas & stuff is mostly not-manned, and for certain not between ~4PM and 8 or 9AM. I've left plenty of time before 8 and after 5 with no one to see me come & go. And if I didn't buy fuel, they'd have no record of my plane having moved at all.

Have tried the [FAA's](https://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation_data_statistics/) Aviation Data & Statistics page?

Answer (score 0):

FlightAware.com can compile runway usage information, based on flight track positions near the airport.  Please reach out if you're still interested in this: https://flightaware.com/commercial/customreports/